# Vue component only updating on console hover, window resize, etc, after FirebaseUI redirect

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a Vue(tify) login using FirebaseUI. The login occurs in a v-dialog and redirects to an "account" page. The relevant script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    let uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: "/account",
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      ]
    },
    return {
      uiConfig: uiConfig
    }
  }
}
```

The account page, on the other hand, looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="user">{{ user.displayName }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = { displayName: user.displayName };
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

My expected behavior: I click one of the login options (let's say Google) and it redirects me to /account. Then it renders the div and shows me my username.

Actual behavior: after redirect the page remains blank. The page renders correctly when I open the drawer, or resize the window, or hover over the Vue developer console in chrome DevTools.

I think this is because the DOM isn't getting rendered successfully... but no matter what I try I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: try lo load user in the mounted and not the created hook.

Comment: No change, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem seems to be how FirebaseUI's SignInSuccessful method plays with vue-router: not well. To avoid this problem I've taken out the method and added a callback that fires on a successful sign in.

```
uiConfig: {
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ],
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function() {this.$router.push({ path: 'account' })}
  }
},
```

With this change the expected behavior is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

the data section in both components should look like:

```
data() {
    return {
      uiConfig: {
        signInSuccessUrl: "/account",
        signInOptions: [
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

```
data() {
    return {
     user: null
    }
  },
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. A typo on my part. I've edited my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Your suggestion was how my code was at the start, but I typed it up here incorrectly.

Comment: can you simplify your code in make an example in jsfiddle?